# Package conflict : hyperref, glossaries, and keyfloat

Tags: hyperref, glossaries, keyfloat

In the code below if I uncomment either of #1 or #2 or #3 it compiles, otherwise not. Why

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{keyfloat} % #1

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.glo}

\newglossaryentry{smith-j}
{
 type=ppl,
 name={Smith, J},
 text={J. Smith},
 description={}
}

\end{filecontents*}
%\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makenoidxglossaries
%\setglossarystyle{tree}
\newglossary*{ppl}{People}
\loadglsentries[ppl]{\jobname.glo}

\usepackage{hyperref} % #2

\author{AUTHOR}

\title{TITLE}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Do you know \gls{smith-j}?

\printnoidxglossaries % #3

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hyperref` loads the `nameref` package. `nameref` patches a number of commands to be able to store their "title" in a label. Beside others `\nameref` patches `\descriptionlabel` and with it you can e.g. reference and link a description item:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
  \item[blub\label{desc:a}] a word
\end{description}

\nameref{desc:a}
\end{document}
```

To get the title `nameref` uses a package named `gettitlestring`. The `keyfloat` package passes to `gettitlestring` the `expand` option:

```
 \PassOptionsToPackage{expand}{gettitlestring}
```

This options makes gettitlestring more powerfull but also more fragile. And now you get errors from the code that glossaries adds to the description labels. It would be possible to teach gettitlestring about glossaries, but as you probably don't need the label titles the easiest is to revert the nameref definition:

```
\makeatletter\let\descriptionlabel\NRorg@descriptionlabel\makeatother
\printnoidxglossaries
```

Comment: Maybe worth pointing the patch must come just before `\printnoidxglossary`.